# Powershell array is not cleared

Tags: arrays, powershell

My source code:

```js
# $arr = @(); results in same behaviour
$arr = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;

$arr.Count;
$arr += "z";

$arr.Count;
$arr.Clear();
$arr.Count;
```

Output:

> 0
>   1
>   1

Comment: Which version of Powershell?  When I run this, `$arr` gets cast to `System.Array` following `$arr += "z"`, so that when I call `Clear()`, I get the following error:  `Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Clear'`

Comment: @David PS 3 on Windows 8 RTM.

Comment: @David You can upgrade;) http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595

Comment: @ComFreek: but you better not, because PS v3 is not backwards compatible with old systems. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Powershell does some array-casting trickery when you do `+=`, so the easy solution is to do `$arr.Add("z")`. Then `$arr.Clear()` will act like you expect.

To clarify:

1. `@()` is a Powershell array. It uses `+=`, but you can't `Clear` it. (You can, however, do `$arr = @()` again to reset it to an empty array.)
2. `ArrayList` is the .NET collection. It uses `.Add`, and you can `Clear` it, but for some reason if you `+=` it, Powershell does some weird array coercion. (If any experts care to comment on this, awesome.)

Comment: Yeah, it's tricky ;) Thanks! For those who have tons of code using `+=`: you can also reinitialize the variable: `$arr = @();`

Comment: But why do I get a `Collection was of a fixed size.` exception when trying to add an item: `$arr = @(); $arr.Add("z");` If I use the ArrayList class, it won't appear.